# Different outputs from similar query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some direction with respect to this query which I have listed below

```
select Count(distinct MemberId) 
from [abc] 
where '2019-07-01' between StartDate and FinishDate"
```

The date value which I have mentioned  here is the startdate for a members enrollment. The `Startdate` field in my table is stored as `(varchar(8), null)`.

The format its stored in the table is like `'20190701'`.

The question is, when I query my table with the startdate as `'2019-07-01'` or `'2019-06-01'` or `'2019-05-01'`, I get the same figure, its not changing at all. Ideally it should give me the count of members whose enrollment starts from that startdate but its giving the same number.

Can you please let me know why that could be.

I was able to get the right answer by using the below query but still would like to know why the query was giving me the wrong figures.

```
select  Count(distinct MemberId) 
from [abc] 
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 20190701, 112) between StartDate and FinishDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a value in a *string* column in the format YYYYMMDD, then your comparison needs to be in the same format:

```
where '20190701' between StartDate and FinishDate
```

I would strongly advise you to store date values as *dates*.  If you had done that, your code would have worked the first time.

Plus, it is highly misleading to have column named `StartDate` *and not store it as a `date`*!

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your help. The question though is still that why did the query I wrote earlier work and even give an output, since the value is stored as varchar and I'm searching it as a string and the format is also completely different.

Comment: @priyesha . . . Because you are comparing *strings* not *dates*.